# Django data migration: Pass argument to RunPython

Tags: python, django, migration

I would like to use data migrations to add and delete groups.

```
from django.db import migrations
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

groups = ["Test Group"]


def add_groups(apps, schema_editor):
    # https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23422
    for group in groups:
        group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name=group)
        if created:
            print(f'Adding group {group}')

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(add_groups),
    ]
```

The function uses the variable from outer scope. I would like to move the function somewhere else so I can reuse it in new migrations. However, it seems that I cannot pass any arguments to the function in RunPython. How can I achieve this with `migrations.RunPython(add_groups(groups=groups))`?

Comment: `RunPython` only accepts callable functions, So I don't think you can do this.

Comment: The ugly way is, override the `RunPython` class appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom class first.

```
from django.db import router


class CustomRunPython(migrations.RunPython):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.context = kwargs.pop('context', {})
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def database_forwards(self, app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state):
        from_state.clear_delayed_apps_cache()
        if router.allow_migrate(schema_editor.connection.alias, app_label, **self.hints):
            self.code(from_state.apps, schema_editor, **self.context)
```

**Note:** Here we are using **`context`** as init parameter which is expected to be a `dict` object.

and now use this new **`CustomRunPython`** in your migration file and pass ***context*** data,

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    operations = [
        CustomRunPython(add_groups, context={'groups': ["Test Group"]}),
    ]
```

and now modify your ***forward function*** to accept the context,

```
def add_groups(apps, schema_editor, **context):
    groups = context['groups']
    for group in groups:
        group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name=group)
        if created:
            print(f'Adding group {group}')
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to add arguments to your call.

```
from functools import partial
from django.db import migrations
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group


def add_group(apps, schema_editor, group):
    # https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23422
    group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name=group)
    if created:
        print(f'Adding group {group}')


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(partial(add_group, group='Test Group')),
    ]
```

Comment: Works like a charm and elegant, highly recommend this over accepted answer